# Derived class' inherited method not working

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods

**Base class:**

```
class Line2D
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Line2D&);
    private:
            Point2D pt1;
            Point2D pt2;
            double length;

    public: 
            Line2D () {pt1 = Point2D(); pt2 = Point2D(); length = 0.0;}
            Line2D (Point2D ptA, Point2D ptB) {pt1=ptA; pt2=ptB; setLength();}
            void setLength();

            void setPt1 (Point2D);
            void setPt2 (Point2D);
            Point2D getPt1 () const;
            Point2D getPt2 () const;
            double getLength() const;    //Inherited to sub-class, but not working in sub-class

};

double Line2D::getLength () const   
{
    return length;
}

void Line2D::setLength()
{
    length = sqrt((pt1.getX() - pt2.getX())*(pt1.getX() - pt2.getX()) + (pt1.getY() - pt2.getY())*(pt1.getY() - pt2.getY()));
}
```

**Derived Class:**

```
class Line3D : public Line2D
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Line3D&);
    private:
            Point3D pt1;
            Point3D pt2;
            double length;

    public: 
            Line3D (Point3D ptA, Point3D ptB) {pt1=ptA; pt2=ptB; setLength();}
            void setLength();

            void setPt1 (Point3D);
            void setPt2 (Point3D);
            Point3D getPt1 () const;
            Point3D getPt2 () const;
};

void Line3D::setLength()
{
    length = sqrt((pt1.getX() - pt2.getX())*(pt1.getX() - pt2.getX()) + (pt1.getY() - pt2.getY())*(pt1.getY() - pt2.getY()) + (pt1.getZ() - pt2.getZ())*(pt1.getZ() - pt2.getZ()));
}
```

I have 2 classes. The derived class inherits method `getLength()` from its base class. However, when I call `getLength()` through a Line3D object (derived class' object), the returned value is always `0.000`.

I `cout` some message in `getLength()` and it shows that the program indeed invoked getLength(). However the returned value is always `0.000`. Why could have possibly went wrong?

There is no error in my codes, but the derived class just unable to get any values via `getLength()`. When I call `getLength()` with a base class object, it has values though.

This is so wierd...

Comment: Why do you define `double length;` in both classes?

Comment: @imreal Because the calculation for length in derived class is different from the base class. It don't inherit length from its parent, it calculate its own length.

Comment: But the data member (not the method) should be just one, or at least be named different, otherwise they hide each other.

Comment: @imreal You got the point, shall I just delete `double length` in the base class and inherit it from its parent?

Comment: Delete it in the derived class, yes.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the `getLength` method always returns the content of the member `length` of the base class, which cannot be written by `setLength` in the derived class, as it is private in the base class. Removing `length` from the derived class and making `length` `protected` in the base class should fix the issue; however I am surprised that the code in the question is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

In `Line3D` a call to `getLength()` is a call to the super-class inherited method, which in turn plays with its "local" (to `Line2D`) `length` attribute.
A call to `setLength()` is a call to the overrided method in Line3D which in turn plays with its "local" (`Line3D`) length attribute.
So when you call `getLength()` you'll have the value of the super class `length` which was probably initialized to zero.
In general it is a very bad design to define an attribute with the same name in a subclass. So delete your `Line3D::length` attribute and only use `getLength()` and `setLength()` methods.
I can suggest you to add a parameter such like `setLength(int v)` and replace call to `setLength()` with a new one with an appropriate value (you may use a private useful `distance()` method to make your computation)